# cassandra key cache not working

Tags: caching, cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise

I am using `DSE 6`. I have default 100 MiB capacity for key cache. But There isn't any hit.

[nodetool info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1v8e.png)

I checked `saved_caches_directory` and there isn't any key cache file.

[cache folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrZLI.png)

My table's description has this attribute:

```
caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
```

and I have enough read the query to build cache.
I don't know where is my problem.

Comment: What is in your key cache?  Please try to create a minimal reproducible example, e.g. assuming that a potential answerer has a fresh Cassandra installation, give instructions to add some sample data, what query you are issuing and how, and what the actual and expected results are.